# use mongooseModel.find() on schema that has a Schema.Types.Mixed property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have trouble using `postModel.find()` query in a schema that defined as `Schema.Types.Mixed`.

this is a sample of my schema

```
 const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  //.....
  address: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  postDetails: {
    type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    required: true,
  },
  author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
 //.....
});
```

this is a sample document stored in db

```
{
        //.....
        "state": "Lakes State",
        "address": "some address",
        "postDetails": {
            "type": "Cages",
            "condition": "Used"
        },
       //......
}
```

it is giving me an empty array if I use this

```
const queryObject = {
  postDetails: {
    type: 'Cages',
  },
};

return this.postModel.find(queryObject);
```

but it gives the desired results  if I include all the properties like this

```
const queryObject = {
  postDetails: {
    type: 'Cages',
    condition: 'Used',
  },
};

return this.postModel.find(queryObject);
```

**How do i get all matching posts that have `postDetails.type = 'Cages'` ? without knowing all available properties inside `postDetails`**

there are some similar questions about this here. but most of them are using arrays instead of an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field) for querying embedded documents

```js
postModel.find({
  "postDetails.type": "Cages"
});
```